# NM coordinator functionality implementation

Tags: shutdown, nm, autosar

Could anyone tell me

1. is it necessary to have Bus Nm implemented for every bus in a NM coordinator cluster??
2. is it possible for synchronised wakeup by NM coordinator??

I have a situation
In my project Flexray and Can networks are implemented.
Flexray has FrNm but CAN doesnt have CANNM module implemented.
CAN is currently handled only via ComM users for example IGK
Requirement is to activate CAN communication even when there is a passive wake up on Fr bus.

Is this scenario can be achieved by
Nm coordinator functioanlity???

Comment: Your questions do not make much sense. There is no "NM coordinator cluster", but maybe coordinated clusters. Some ECUs can take over the role as an NmCoordinator and must therefore at least be connected to at least 2 networks, though, they can be just plain Nm Node (no NmCoordinator)  on a higher cluster. Using NM on depends also a lot on the topology itself, including the difference between CL30 and (several kinds of) CL15 ECUs. CL15 Nodes could also be passive or none NmNodes. A private CAN between 2 ECUs, which are also connected to a different NmCluster does not need NM on CAN either.